# How to set file association for all users (Windows Server)

Tags: sql-server, file-association, perl, windows-server

We run our jobs through SSMS on Windows Server. Our IT support has built a new server for us, virtual, with Windows Server 2016 Datacenter and SSMS 15.0, and copied over all jobs from the current server. Most job steps are CmdExec steps running under SQL Server Agent Service Account. They work except for one thing: the association of .pl files with perl (Strawberry Perl).

For instance, if we run "myscript.pl …" it doesn't fail, but it doesn't run through the perl interpreter. As a workaround, we can say "perl myscript.pl …", but there are many steps that use perl, so changing all of them would be onerous. The scripts work on the current server.

I have admin rights on the server. '.pl' is associated with Perl for me – I can run scripts from the command line without saying "perl" first – but apparently not for the Service Account. Ideally, I'd like to set this once for all users. I suspect this could be fixed through a GPO but haven't found instructions that clearly apply to WS2016.

Comment: `if we run "myscript.pl …" it doesn't fail` : So what happens?

Comment: The job ends normally, but nothing shows in the log. I suppose it gets opened with Notepad or something else innocuous.

Comment: Could you get the PATH in that environment, perhaps by running a `.bat` with "path >file". Ensure that perl is in the PATH of SYSTEM. A useful utility is [System Path Commander](https://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/System-Enhancements/Windows-Portable-Applications-Portable-System-Path-Commander.shtml).

Comment: Good thought, but no luck. The path includes C:\Strawberry\perl\bin etc., but the script is not executed through perl.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the file-type associations by using in Command Prompt the commands:

```
assoc .pl                          (might give PerlScript)
ftype PerlScript
```

Ensure that the `ftype` command gives the full path to `perl`.

Check their values in the `CmdExec` environment by running the commands like:

```
assoc .pl > \path\to\file
ftype PerlScript >> \path\to\file
```

If the values are wrong, try to set them by running in an elevated CmdExec:

```
assoc .pl=PerlScript
ftype PerlScript=c:\path\to\perl.exe %1 %*
```

Comment: Nice tip. Unfortunately, no effect on the problem. Also, "ftype" on the current server shows no path for Perl, but it works there.

Comment: What do these commands give as value in the CmdExec environment?

Comment: `>assoc .pl`
`.pl=Perl_program_file`

`>ftype Perl_program_file`
`Perl_program_file=C:\Strawberry\Perl\bin\perl.exe %1 %*`

Comment: There is no reason then for perl scripts not to work. Have you tried a minuscule script that just gives a sign of life such as writing to a file?

Comment: Yes, I have. Wrote a small script that just printed one line to stdout and wrote a file. When it's called as smallish.pl, nothing happens; when called as "perl smallish.pl", it works.

Comment: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573385/perl-strawberry-how-to-run-a-perl-script-by-clicking) which seems very similar to your problem, where it is explained as a problem of folder execution context. Try to add the magic code in the accepted answer to smallish.pl to see if this makes a difference.

Comment: There is also [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727480/how-do-i-make-my-perl-scripts-act-like-normal-programs-on-windows) which advises adding  .PL to your PATHEXT environment variable to make Windows consider `.pl` files to be executable when searching your PATH.

Comment: You should also check in the registry what is under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pl\UserChoice`.